# How to check SharePoint Client Object Model is enabled or not?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to check programmatically (VS 2010 & C#) whether Microsoft SharePoint Client Object Model is supported in a server or not?

When I connected to a 2007 SharePoint site using Microsoft SharePoint Client Object Model, I got "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.". As the exception is generic, I'm skeptical to trap this exception and consider that the server doesn't support  SharePoint Client Object Model. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "When I connected to a 2007 SharePoint" I guess you mean SP 2010 here? Since there is no client object model in SP 2007

Comment: No, I mean SP 2007 only. I know that there is no client object model (COM) in SP 2007, but how do I ensure this programmatically is my question. The logic i'm building for my tool is "If SP COM is not supported then use SP webservices".